# Read bytes only after EOF markup in c#

Tags: c#, eof, steganography

So I am playing with steganography a bit, and after text/images/sound/videos I am trying to do smth with executable files. There is known method of placing hidden message after EOF in those files. It's working for me to certain point, but I wonder if I could start reading the hidden message only after EOF, instead of all the bytes.

I have the code that read .exe to byte array and put additional info in those bytes:

```
public byte[] CreateHiddenMessage(byte[] container, byte[] message)
{
    byte[] newArray = new byte[container.Length + message.Length];

    //copy original bytes
    for (int i = 0; i < container.Length; i++)
    {
        newArray[i] = container[i];
    }

    //add hidden info
    for (int i = 0; i < message.Length; i++)
    {
        newArray[i + container.Length] = message[i];
    }

    return newArray;
}
```

Then, I save those bytes without any problem like:

```
public static void WriteToFile(String name, byte[] bytesToSave)
{
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(name, bytesToSave);
}
```

**And now ther is a problem I am facing**. The new executable file works great, it has those additional bytes, but when I am trying to retreive hidden message, I have to go through all of those bytes and print them in my application (a lot of random signs first, then the actual message).

Is there any way to start reading those hidden bytes (and converting to chars) only after EOF markup has appeard? I know there is no such thing like "EOF character", but still, any ideas?

My only idea was to put some kind of header-thingy code at the start of hiding message in original file, like "##$$##[message]", and then after reading all the bytes just start converting characters after this code. But I would like to avoid it!

Comment: Don't avoid it. Do it.
Or else, at the very end of the message, add a 32 bit number with the exact length of the message. Then read only that ammount of bytes from the end.

Comment: My best suggestion is to add the length of the message at the end of the file as an example 45, then you would read 45 characters from the last position, this way you don't need to read all the characters to find your message, you know where your message is located and how long it is.

Comment: Oh this is actually really good idea, to place the number indicating length of the hidden message. I will apply it to the code. This way I don't need to go through all the bytes (and for exe files its often a lof ot them) with a low cost (like 4 additional bytes for 32bit number at the end of the message).

Answer (score 1):

So I've decided to go with the idea of [Gerardo Grignoli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/97471/gerardo-grignoli) and write the length of the hidden message at the end of executable that is holding the message.